# Canvas with ruler control in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

Is there a control or something similar to a canvas with a margin(ruler), like in MS Word,
in .NET WPF or WinForms?

I need to place some custom elements inside that user can modify in that canvas.

[image]